# Asus p7p55-m will not pick the extra 4G of memory

Tags: memory, installation

So here's the problem: I've got this Asus p7p55-m motherboard that was originally purchased with 4Gs of memory and it all worked well until I wanted to drop extra memory in it (KVR1333D3N9K2 model). So I purchased another 4G of the same memory and bios will show 4g of *usable* memory and Win7 (x64) will show 8G installed (4G usable). Perhaps, someone can suggest something on this eh?

Initially the memory was located in A1 and B1 slots:

A1 A2 B1 B2

so I added the extra ones into A2 and B2 respectively and then tried swapping everything the was that old memory was sitting in A1 and A2 and new ones in B1 and B2 neither seemed to work out.

Here are a few screenshots in case this may be helpful.

[image: motherboard info]

[image: memory info]

[image: bank 1]

[image: bank 2]

[image: bank 3]

[image: bank 4]

Thanks all for any advises.

Comment: Yep, that is odd.  The memory timings look the same, your motherboard [claims to support](http://uk.asus.com/Motherboards/Intel_Socket_1156/P7P55M/#specifications) up to 16GB.  The only thing different is the part number on the memory stick and I wouldn't expect that to be a problem.

Comment: What is your processor out of curiosity?  Since your memory is no longer actually controlled by your motherboard (though the motherboard does matter) you may want to check how much memory your processor supports.

Comment: @Mokubai thanks for looking into this - indeed I'd expect this to kind of work out :) I'm worried the memory is running in single mode (it's KVR1333D3N9K2 model). The processor is Intel i7 870 Lynnfield.

Comment: Both the CPU's datasheet and the motherboard's qualified vendor list indicate that your new memory modules are supported, so this is really a mistery. What is the model of your old RAM?

Comment: @billc.cn same model, mate.

Comment: Then maybe it's an option in the BIOS or the BIOS itself. Maybe you should try updating your BIOS to the latest version and reload the defaults.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I upgraded the BIOS to its latest revision and kept swapping the memory around and at the end of all I have the 8Gigs now. Not sure what exactly has helped, it could be that I haven't firmly pushed the chips in or something (but if that - how did CPU-Z detect all my memory). Anyhow, this is considered solved.

Comment: As you have solved your problem you should be able to mark you answer as correct.